# como jogar letra por letra de uma frase em uma matriz?

Tags: c, string, matriz

Exemplo: na frase `naruto`, a letra `n` do vetor `frase` está na posição `frase[0]`.

Quero colocá-la na `mat_cript` posiçao `[0][0]`. 
Não só ela, o restante da frase também.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()

{
char frase[25];
    char mat_cript[i][j];
    int chave, tamanho_frase, cont,i,j;

    system("cls");

    printf("Digite a frase a ser criptografada : ");
    gets(frase);

    while(chave<1 || chave>25)
    {
        printf("Digite a chave a ser utilizada (<= 25) : ");
        scanf("%d",&chave);
        fflush(stdin);
    }

    tamanho_frase = strlen(frase);
    for(cont=0;cont<tamanho_frase;cont++)
        frase[cont] = frase[cont]+chave;

    printf("\n\nFRASE CRIPTOGRAFADA : %s",frase);
    getchar();

    for(i=0;i < tamanho_frase;i++){
        for(j=0;j< tamanho_frase;j++){
            mat_cript[i][j]=frase[i];
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i < tamanho_frase;i++){
        for(j=0;j< tamanho_frase;j++){
            printf(" %d°elemento da linha %d, coluna %d: %s",j+1;i+1;j+1;mat_cript[i][j]);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer isso, basta ter o controle das linhas de sua matriz e inserir cada caractere na matriz separadamente. Você deve atribuir cada caractere da frase em uma posição da matriz.

Nesse exemplo, foi colocado o caractere `-` em todas as posições de uma matriz, depois foi contado a quantidade de caractere da frase e colocado cada caractere em uma posição na matriz:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> 

main(){
    char valid_chars[27];

    char mat_cript[10][10];
    char frase[10];

    srand(time(NULL));

    strcpy(valid_chars, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

    strcpy(frase, "naruto");
    int num = strlen(frase);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            int control = (rand() % 26);

            mat_cript[i][j] = valid_chars[control];;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        mat_cript[5][i] = frase[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            printf("\t%c", mat_cript[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/rqT3Oh).

Comment: Oi Gabriel , como ficaria para uma frase de n caracteres e preenchendo o restante dos índices com caracteres aleatórios

Comment: @Roni editei a resposta. Primeiro ele já pega a partir de `n` caracteres, que é o que ele faz em `strlen(frase);`. No código ele seta valores aleatórios e depois, preenche com a frase que você quer, de acordo com a posição que deseja, aí é do seu controle onde vai ser inserido.

Comment: obrigado, estou fazendo uma criptografia de transposição e sinceramente ...não sei se vou conseguir.

Comment: @Roni se a resposta te ajudou, marque-a como aceita e tente fazer sim, qualquer dúvida, só chamar